# Referencing User Schema inside a User schema (and using the populate method with it)? Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to create an application using mongoose. I have a User Schema. User's can follow other Users (similar to how Twitter or Instagram work.

Here is my UserSchema:

```
let UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    },
    following: {
        type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
        ref: 'User'
    },
    followers: {
        type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
        ref: 'User'
    }
})
```

I am trying to create a route that will display a user's follower's  and following information, such as their name and id. So, I tried something like this:

```
User.findOne({ _id: req.session.user }).populate('follower',['username']).then((user) => {
        res.send(user);
    })
```

However, the json that is being returned is:

```
   {
      "_id":"5a1dec7280a69b417a170e92",
      "username":"vegeta",
      "email":"vegeta@gmail.com",
      "__v":0,
      "followers":[
         "5a1dec7280a69b417a170e92",
         "5a1dedb9a88aad42cad87dde"
      ],
      "following":[
         "5a1dec7280a69b417a170e92",
         "5a1dedb9a88aad42cad87dde"
      ],
      "password":"$2a$10$ZsEpC6LoE0I.FzsTtPo2IOBICRGoYsFV0s2RVNcCW/g9VO4ErGaKW"
   }
```

Instead, I would like to see information about the follower and following so, something like:

```
   {
      "_id":"5a1dec7280a69b417a170e92",
      "username":"vegeta",
      "email":"vegeta@gmail.com",
      "__v":0,
      "followers":[
         {
            _id: "5a1dec7280a69b417a170e92",
            username: "vegeta"
         },
         {
            _id: "5a1dedb9a88aad42cad87dde",
            username: "goku"
         }
      ],
      "following":[
         {
            _id: "5a1dec7280a69b417a170e92",
            username: "vegeta"
         },
         {
            _id: "5a1dedb9a88aad42cad87dde",
            username: "goku"
         }
      ],
      "password":"$2a$10$ZsEpC6LoE0I.FzsTtPo2IOBICRGoYsFV0s2RVNcCW/g9VO4ErGaKW"
   }
```

How can I fix my User.findOne method to solve my issue?

Comment: Edit your schema from `type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId]` to a custom type with a username and id.

Answer (score 0):

Schema can be changed as below to get it work, as we can use the Object in Scheme.

```
let UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String },
  following: [{ 
    _id: { type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId], ref: 'User' },
    username: { type: String,  ref: 'User' } 
  }],
  followers: [{ 
    _id: { type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId], ref: 'User' },
    username: { type: String,  ref: 'User' }
  }]
})
```

Refer to [Mongoose Schema Types](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) for more details. Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a difference or practical benefit to using that (the code in your answer) vs something like: followers: [{
   _id: {type: 'String'},
  username: {type: 'String'}
}]

Comment: Using the code in my answer, you do not have expose mongo **_id** to front end and use **username** instead as it is unique, thus it is more secure.

Comment: Also we cannot use _id as key under Following or Followers

Comment: I have already used the '_id' key in my Schema and I am currently not getting any errors. Is this just a bad practice, or is that from the docs saying we cannot use _id as a key?

Comment: As far as you use the mongo generated _id values, it is fine. But, if you by chance if you pass any other value, it may conflict since mongo uses it's own hashing mechanism to manage the _id

Comment: Also, can you tell me why it is more secure to leave username client side, and not expose _id to the client? I've seen a lot of routing that's based on ids. For instance, site.com/user/:id or site.com/posts/:id, site.com/posts/update/:id . Why is exposing ID to the client not secure?

Comment: @mdash1, it is good practice to not to expose the Primary Keys in RDBMS and you can find number of articles on this, if you just Google it. as the Object ID(_Id) in NoSQL (Mongo in this case) is same as Primary Keys in RDMS for referencing other documents.